# Is it correct that saving an address with only Country should fail to save data?

Tags: contacts

On Demo if you go to this record http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=202 and 'add address' or 'Edit' and save the Home Address with just Country (currently set to Default Country = Australia), nothing gets saved, no debug message either.

I tested on demo after witnessing what I thought was a problem with a Profile on a Contribution page, but the issue seems to be actually with the 'save contact' task.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a default country and that you save an address with only that country, it assumes it's not that the user chose this country, but just that the default was left selected.

So it's normal behaviour, but might not be what you want indeed.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. And your explanation makes sense somewhat in the context of 'add address' or 'edit' but in the case of a Profile that has the Country field required, and where we only 'require' country it seems to be failing us - though at least I know now (hopefully) that the only data we failed to collect was when country was Default, and if they set the country to something other than Default then the data would have been saved.

Comment: Okay..so if I only want to save the country for my contacts (which is my case, I have many international contacts and don't need to save all contact details..just the country) then CiviCRM refuses to save it, and there appears no way to save the country? I have submitted this as a bug because I don't think this should be seen as normal behavior. Or maybe I have missed something? https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16989